# Deploying DB2 user define functions in sequence of dependency

Tags: db2, user-defined-functions

We have about 200 user define functions in DB2.  These UDF are generated by datastudio into a single script file.

When we create a new DB, we need to run the script file several times because some UDF are dependent on other UDF and cannot be create until the precedent functions are created first.

Is there a way to generate a script file so that the order they are deployed take into account this dependency.  Or is there some other technique to arrange the order efficiently?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem should only happen if the setting of [auto_reval](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0053784.html) is not correct. See "[Creating and maintaining database objects](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/r0054951.html)" for details.

Db2 allows to create objects in an "unsorted" order. Only when the object is used (accessed), the objects and its depending objects are checked. The behavior was introduced a long time ago. Only some old, migrated databases keep **auto_reval=disabled**. Some environments might set it based on some configuration scripts.

if you still run into issues, try setting **auto_reval=DEFERRED_FORCE**.

Comment: Thanks you @data_henrik.  This has worked.  And apologies for my late reply.  Appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 0):

The [`db2look`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002051.html) system command can generate DDL by by object creation time with the `-ct` option, so that can help if you don't want to use the `auto_reval` method.